# How can we handle multiple click events using one function in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to handle multiple click events of bootstrap accordion tab in one function, but unable to handle that. I want the functionality Like that:-

(1) If user click on any accordion tab then the icon should be change to minus(-).

(2) If user click on any accordion tab then all other opened tab should be closed.

I am able to do this using different function for every tab. but I have to handle this using only one function as I have Multiple tabs.

here is my html code:-

```
<div ng-controller="TabController">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <a class="accordion-toggle" ng-click="clickOnTab($event,'FirstTab')" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="javascript:void(0),#collapseOne">
                            <div class="mid-col">
                                <h5>First Tab</h5> 
                            </div>
                            <div class="right-col">
                                <div ng-class="{false:'glyphicon glyphicon-plus',true:'glyphicon glyphicon-minus'}[tabicon == 'FirstTab']"></div>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                        <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                            <div class="panel-body">                
                                This is content of First Tab<br/>
                                    1. When The Tab is open the Icon Should be Minus (-). It is working Fine When you are playing with only one tab. But when you try to open another tab while this tab is currently open then Iam getting issue.
                             <br/> 2. When you open tab all other (Opened) tab should be closed. 

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
        </div>

          <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <a class="accordion-toggle" ng-click="clickOnTab($event,'SecondTab')" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="javascript:void(0),#collapseTwo">
                            <div class="mid-col">
                                <h5>Second Tab</h5> 
                            </div>
                            <div class="right-col">
                                <div ng-class="{false:'glyphicon glyphicon-plus',true:'glyphicon glyphicon-minus'}[tabicon == 'SecondTab']"></div>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                        <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                            <div class="panel-body">                
                                This is content of Second Tab<br/>
                                    1. When The Tab is open the Icon Should be Minus (-). It is working Fine When you are playing with only one tab. But when you try to open another tab while this tab is currently open then Iam getting issue.
                             <br/> 2. When you open tab all other (Opened) tab should be closed. 
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
        </div>


          <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <a class="accordion-toggle" ng-click="clickOnTab($event,'ThirdTab')" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="javascript:void(0),#collapseThree">
                            <div class="mid-col">
                                <h5>First Tab</h5> 
                            </div>
                            <div class="right-col">
                                <div ng-class="{false:'glyphicon glyphicon-plus',true:'glyphicon glyphicon-minus'}[tabicon == 'ThirdTab']"></div>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                        <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                            <div class="panel-body">                
                                This is content of Third Tab<br/>
                                    1. When The Tab is open the Icon Should be Minus (-). It is working Fine When you are playing with only one tab. But when you try to open another tab while this tab is currently open then Iam getting issue.
                             <br/> 2. When you open tab all other (Opened) tab should be closed. 

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
        </div>
```

Here is the Controller:-

```
var myapp = angular.module('plunker', []);

myapp.controller("TabController",function($scope){

  $scope.clickOnTab = function($event,val){
                console.log($event);
                //console.log($event.currentTarget);

                $scope.tabrighticon = !$scope.tabrighticon;

                console.log($scope.tabrighticon);

                if($scope.tabrighticon)
                    $scope.tabicon = val;
                else
                    $scope.tabicon = 1; 
    };

});
```

[Here is the plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/qqyeLt26M2WeiscoEKtN?p=preview)

Comment: can solution be in jquery ? because i see you included it

Comment: [Angular ui bootstrap accordion directive](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/accordion) has implemented exactly what you need.

Comment: @MarkoMackic  It will be good that if I will be getting the answer in angular or javascript way. :)

Comment: @Jax  I can't add additional script as i have some restrictions. I have to implement this functionality by using available scripts which I am using currently.